# \underbrace in bordermatrix

Tags: bordermatrix

Is there a possibility to use `\underbrace` in a `\bordermatrix`? I want to underbrace some elements in the last row of the matrix, but it is important that it stays a bordermatrix, because I need the first row over the matrix.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: Can you put together and post some code that at least tries to do what you want?  It would help readers to see your intent better. Welcome to the site.